# A field of definition of an affine $k$-variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We fix an algebraically closed field $\Omega$ which has infinite trancendence dimension over the prime subfield.
A subfield $k$ of $\Omega$ such that tr.dim $\Omega/k = \infty$ is called an admissible field.

Let $V$ be a Zariski closed subset of $\Omega^n$.
Let $I = \{f \in \Omega[X_1,\dots,X_n]|\ f(p) = 0$ for every $p \in V\}$.
Let $k$ be an admissible field such that $I$ has a basis in $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.
Then we say $k$ is a field of definition of $V$.

Let $k$ be an admissible field.
Let $V$ be a $k$-closed subset in $\Omega^n$(see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246226/relation-between-a-generalization-of-weils-abstract-varieties-and-algebraic-sch) for the definition of a $k$-closed subset).
Let $I_k(V) = \{f \in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]|\ f(p) = 0$ for every $p \in V\}$.
Let $A = k[X_1,\dots,X_n]/I_k(V)$.
Then what condition should $A$ satisfy for $k$ to be a field of definition of $V$?

Comment: If $V$ is a $k$-closed subset, shouldn't $k$ automatically be a field of definition of $V$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Suppose $char(\Omega) = p > 0$.
Let $F$ be the prime subfield of $\Omega$.
Let $t$ be an element of $\Omega$ such that $F(t)/F$ is not algebraic.
Let $k = F(t)$.
Let $\alpha$ be a root of $X^p - t$ in $\Omega$.
Since $\alpha$ is a unique root of $X^p - t$, $V = \{\alpha\}$ is $k$-closed.
But $k$ is not a field of definition of $V$ because $\alpha$ is not an element of $k$.

Comment: ah yes, I forgot that a "field of definition" of a variety is not just a field over which the variety is definable.