# Is a common field of definition of all the irreducible components of an affine algebraic variety a field of definition of itself?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We use the definitions of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246968/a-field-of-definition-of-an-affine-k-variety).
Let $V$ be a Zariski closed subset of $\Omega^n$.
Let $V_1,\dots,V_r$ be all the irreducible components of $V$.
Let $k$ be a common field of definition of all $V_i$.
Is $k$ a field of definition of $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ and $W$ are closed subsets of $\mathbf{A}^n_{K}$ and $k$ is a common field of definition for $V$ and $W$, it is easy to see that $k$ is a field of definition for $V\cup W$. You can check this locally. Then, it boils down to the statement that if $I$ and $J$ are ideals in $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ which can be generated by elements in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then $I\cdot J$ is also generated by such elements.