# Products in a subcategory

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a full subcategory of a category $\mathcal{C}$.
Let $X, Y$ be objects of $\mathcal{D}$.
Suppose a product $X\times Y$ exists in $\mathcal{C}$.
Suppose $X\times Y$ is not isomorphic to any object of $\mathcal{D}$.
Can we conclude that a product of $X$ and $Y$ does not exist in $\mathcal{D}$?
If not, any counter-example?

Comment: Taking C to be the category of finite abelian groups and D the subcat. of cyclic groups of prime order you can find an example,  I think.

Comment: Another quick example is for instance ${\cal D}=\textbf{Fields}$ and
${\cal C}=\textbf{CommRings}$. The product of two rings can never be a field,
but some products exist in the category of fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two counter-examples: one quite well-known and important, and one more elementary.

The important example: [compactly generated (Hausdorff) topological spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space) (briefly, *k-spaces*).  The full subcategory of **Top** of these, **kHaus**, is a very nice category of spaces — better-behaved in many ways than **Top** itself.

Anyhow, the ordinary topological product of two k-spaces may not itself be a k-space; but it has an associated space (sometimes called its “k-ification”) which, while not a product in **Top**, is a product in **kHaus**.

The more elementary example is with coproducts not products, but sticking “op” on the categories involved makes it an example with products.  Here, consider Abelian groups, **AbGp**, as a subcategory of all groups, **Grp**.  The coproduct of two groups $A, B$ in **Gp** is their free product $A \ast B$.  For Abelian $A$, $B$, the free product will usually not be Abelian: for instance, $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$ is the free group on two generators.  However, they do also have a coproduct in **AbGp**, given by $A \oplus B$.

---

There’s a nice explanation for both these examples, and indeed for all the natural examples of this situation that I can think of.

Suppose **D** is a *reflective* subcategory of **C**, i.e. the inclusion functor has a left adjoint.  (The Abelianisation functor **Gp** $\to$ **AbGp** is a typical example.)  Then coproducts in **D** — more generally, any colimits — can be computed by taking the colimit in **C** and applying the reflector to the result.  So, for instance, $A \oplus B$ is the Abelianisation of $A \ast B$.  Checking that this recipe works whenever the colimits exist in **C** is a short diagram-chase — it’s essentially the fact that left adjoints preserve colimits.

Dually, if **D** is *co-reflective* — the inclusion has a *right* adjoint — then products (and arbitrary limits) can be computed in a similar fashion.

Reflective and co-reflective categories arise very often in nature; so they give lots of good examples where the (co)product in the ambient category doesn’t lie in the subcategory, but the subcategory has its own product nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

No. There's no reason for the inclusion of $D$ into $C$ to preserve products. Peter LeFanu Lumsdain has given some nice examples.

However, one situation in which the inclusion of $D$ into $C$ is guaranteed to preserve products is when it has a left adjoint (in which case the inclusion in fact preserves all limits). In this case, $D$ is said to be a [reflective subcategory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory), and then the desired conclusion holds. For example:

- Compact Hausdorff spaces are a reflective subcategory of topological spaces (the adjoint is Stone-Čech compactification).
- Abelian groups are a reflective subcategory of groups (the adjoint is abelianization).
- Sheaves are a reflective subcategory of presheaves (the adjoint is sheafification).