# Relation between affine $k$-varieties and affine schemes of finite type over k.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a map between topological spaces.
Let $\mathfrak{O}(X)$(resp. $\mathfrak{O}(Y))$ be the set of open subsets of $X$(resp. $Y$).
Suppose the application $U \rightarrow f^{-1}(U)$ is a bijection $\mathfrak{O}(Y) \rightarrow \mathfrak{O}(X)$. Then $f$ is called a quasi-homeomorphism.

Now we use the definitions of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246226/relation-between-a-generalization-of-weils-abstract-varieties-and-algebraic-sch).
Let $k$ be a field and $X$ be an affine $k$-variety.
Let $A = \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$.
Let $x \in X$.
We denote $\{f \in A|\ f(x) = 0\}$ by $\mathfrak{p}_x$.
It is a prime ideal of $A$.
Hence we get a map $\psi\colon X \rightarrow Spec(A)$ by defining $\psi(x) = \mathfrak{p}_x$.

Let $Y = Spec(A)$.
Let $f \in A$.
Let $h \in A_f = \Gamma(D(f), \mathcal{O}_Y)$.
Then $h$ is identified with a regular function on $\psi^{-1}(D(f))$ in $Y$.
Hence we get a canonical map $\psi_U^{\#}\colon \Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_Y) \rightarrow \Gamma(\psi^{-1}(U),\mathcal{O}_X)$ for any open subset $U$ of $Y$.
Are the following assertions true?

(1) $\psi$ is a quasi-homeomorphism.

(2) $\psi_U^{\#}\colon \Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_Y) \rightarrow \Gamma(\psi^{-1}(U),\mathcal{O}_X)$ is an isomorphism of $k$-algebras for any open subset $U$ of $Y$.

Comment: Probably you mean that $V \mapsto f^{-1}(V)$ is a bijection from $\mathfrak{O}(Y) \to \mathfrak{O}(X)$.

Comment: @Adeel Right. Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of quasi-homeomorphism? A homeomorphism outside a closed set?

Comment: @FredrikMeyer A quasi-homeomorphism is a map $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ of topological spaces satisfying the above condition.